# Where goes the return of ConfigureServices by Autofac in .netcore 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, autofac

i are using the Autofac Framework in .netcore and in the implementation I need to use this code in Startup.cs:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //another codes
    return services.RegisterAutoFac();
}
```

and my function RegisterAutoFac() is:

```
public static class AutofacConfig
{
    public static IServiceProvider RegisterAutoFac(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<AdministradorRepository>().As<IAdministradorRepository>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<CassinoRepository>().As<ICassinoRepository>();

        return containerBuilder.Build() as IServiceProvider;
    }
}
```

I'm starting now in Autofac and i can't find what this **return services.RegisterAutoFac()** in ConfigureServices means, someone can tell me where does the return go? Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 2):

Your ConfigureServices needs return type of `IServiceProvider`

`RegisterAutoFac` extension returns IServiceProvider thus,

```
return services.RegisterAutoFac();
```

builds `ServiceProvider` and returns it as `IServiceProvider`